# swift uiwebview NSErrorFailingURLStringKey

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

How do I print the value of `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey` in swift for a UIWebView's `didFailLoadWithError`?

I have `localizedDescription` and other options for `NSError` but looking for `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey` String.

Is this possible? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first, your question not saying clear.

```
var res = (task.response as! HTTPURLResponse)
print(" status code ->\(Int((res as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode))")
do {
    if res.statusCode == 440 {
        // handel error here.
    }
    else if res.statusCode == 308 {
        // handel error here.
    }
    else if res.statusCode == 400 || res.statusCode == 500 {
        var dictFromData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(withData: error.userInfo![AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey], options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments)!
        // handel error here.
    }
    else {
        // handel error here.
    }

}
catch {
}
```